# APK file gets corrupted while writing to SD Card

Tags: java, android, file, apk, httpresponse

I hit to a URL where my apk file is hosted and then write the bytes received to a file.

```
class DownloadAPKFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    private byte[] fileBytes;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.d("begin", "begun");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.website/Path/my.apk");


        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            Log.d("Login", "Response " + response.getEntity());
            Log.d("Login", "contentLength " + response.getEntity().getContentLength());
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            fileBytes = responseBody.getBytes();

            Log.d("fileBytes", "fileBytes");
            String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/myappdir/" + "my" + ".apk";

            File file = new File(filePath);
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            file.createNewFile();

            BufferedOutputStream objectOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            Log.d("objectOut", "objectOut");
            objectOut.write(fileBytes);
            Log.d("write", "write");
            objectOut.close();



        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

}
```

This works like a charm, the problem i am having is that the content length from the entitiy is `582504` but when i look into the file manager the size goes upto `863145`. I think that some data is being added while writing file to SD Card. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, my apk has 873kb when I export it.
After I download it through the app it has 910 and sometimes 916kb...
Also, it's an invalid zip and Android can't read package info. Giving me that analisis error while trying to install.

Answer (score -1):

This is my code which works fine, please check if this works for you

```
public class downloadApk extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>
    {


        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://www.tagsinfosoft.com/android/shelf/Shelf_Cam.apk");
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.setDoOutput(true);
                c.connect();

                String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, "Shelf_Cam.apk");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();//till here, it works fine - .apk is download to my sdcard in download file

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Context context=shelf.this;
            pd.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "Shelf_Cam.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);  

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd=ProgressDialog.show(shelf.this,"Updating","Please wait....." );
        }

    }
```

Comment: That may be well and good for other ways, what I want is a solution to my method.

Comment: it's 5-6 lines different than yours,if it's the case of corrupt file then it surely helps and if it's memory issue it doesn't matter as long as the apk is usable.